# Common method to be called for all CREATE, UPDATE and DESTROY actions for all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, crud

I am trying to create database logs for all CRUD actions. I know I can go to each controller action and insert the method to get it working. Is there a way to do this more elegantly so the methods get called for all the controllers before a CRUD action takes place. These are the methods I am using:

## To create transaction

```
TransactionLog.create(:contact_id => contact_id) #Create the transaction
```

## To create the changelog

```
def self.start_logging(current_user, data, action, new_content ={}, old_content ={}, transaction_log_id)
  @log = ChangeLog.new(:table => data, :action => action, :new_content => new_content.to_json, :old_content => old_content.to_json, :transaction_log_id => transaction_log_id)
  @log.save
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The before_filter idea is the way to go. What's missing in the other answers is how to apply this to all your controllers. The best option is to create a mixin with the code that defines and activates the filter.

```
module HasCrudFilter
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      before_filter :my_filter, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

      def my_filter
        #  Your code here...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controllers

```
class MyModelController < ApplicationController
  include HasCrudFilter
end
```

Comment: Do I add the mixin code in application_controller.rb? Do I have to include it in all the controllers?

Comment: You would include the mixin only in the controllers that require the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Filters  (Refer Section 8 here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
before_filter :your_method, only: ['create', 'update' 'destroy']

def your_method
  #do the things
end
```